# Trying to create a new application in Yii: env: php: No such file or directory

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to create a new yii app from the terminal. My YiiRoot folder is in my htdoc folder. I'm first going into my webroot:

```
$ cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
```

I'm then going into yiic and trying to create a new application:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp demo
```

I'm then getting this message:

```
env: php: No such file or directory
```

I've also tried:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/YiiRoot/framework
yiic webapp /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
-bash: yiic: command not found
```

And:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/YiiRoot/framework 
./yiic webapp /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
 No such file or directory
```

And:

```
 cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/YiiRoot/framework 
 php yiic webapp /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
 -bash: php: command not found
```

And:

```
 cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/YiiRoot/framework 
 php yiic.php webapp /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
 -bash: php: command not found
```

I'm completely out of ideas. Any advice please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, my particular problem was that php was somehow erased of my system. When I typed `find /usr -name php` into the terminal there was no indication that the `/bin/php` file existed. So I asked another question on stackoverflow in an attempt to trouble shoot my php command line problem. So the answer to this question is actually the answer to that question which can be found [HERE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557650/how-can-i-get-php-working-again-in-the-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the `php-cli` package for your disro.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty common. You need to edit the file Yiic.bat, which is in the folder  yii/framwork. There you'll find the line

> PHP_COMMAND

Its predifine value usually is just "php.exe". Change that value to the actual address of your php.exe file.  Assuming you have a MAMP installation, you could find the php.exe file in the  mamp/php/ folder, so the value to PHP_COMMAND would be:

root:/address_to_mamp/mamp/php/php.exe

Comment: I tried looking for the php.exe file but it's not in that location so I searched for it in the spotlight and it doesn't exist. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: MAMP stands for "**Mac**, Apache, MySQL, PHP". I don't think any `.exe` is involved.

Comment: That's true, sorry. I thought it was a linux/windows apache installation. Then, all you have to do is find the corresponding file for your OS and update its address where I told you