# How can I get PHP working again in the command line?

Tags: php, command-line, osx-lion

I'm completely at loss here and am about to wipe my hard drive clean and start from a fresh OS install. I've been trying for two days to create a new yii app in the terminal and have finally figured out that the terminal or command line can not even execute PHP all of a sudden. I had no problem in past creating an executing php from the command line, But now it's not working. When I type **which php** i get nothing. When I type **php -v** I get:

```
 -bash: php: command not found.
```

And when I try to create a new yii application I get:

```
env: php: No such file or directory
```

I am using mac osx-lion and my path looks like this at the moment:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

I've tried looking through the php manual and I'm getting nowhere. How can I reconfigure the command line to execute php? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what your distribution is but you might want to check if the php package is installed?

Comment: I assume you may not have php in your PATH variable. In Linux Mint, php was installed in /usr/bin/. Try /usr/bin/php -v and see if that works. If so, follow one of the suggestions from the answers below.

Comment: @EmmanuelG I tried that and Im getting No such file or directory. I can't find it anywhere and am beginning to wonder if it's even installed any longer.

Comment: You could check it out with a package manager.  For ubuntu it's php-cli or php5-cli, I'm not sure.  It would help if you would mention what distribution you are using :).

Comment: @Zombaya sorry about that, I'm using lion

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hopefully this will save someone a lot of headache. If, for whatever reason, you are unable to locate php in your command line, and unable to execute php from the command line, below is a list of steps to get PHP up and running again.

1. double check to make sure PHP is no where to be found by opening your terminal, and typing
   `find /usr -name php` and hit enter. The main thing you want to look for here is a path with `/bin/php` at
   the end. In my case it's, now that I've installed it, it's `/usr/local/php5-20120508-102213/bin/php`. If you don't see anything like that then go to the next step. If you see something like that then make note of that path with the `/bin/php` at the end, and go to step 4.
2. Go to the terminal and type in `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.4`,
   hit enter. It will ask for your password. Your installing a php package. After you enter  your password just follow the steps like any other download. For more information on that download you can visit [the binary package website.](http://php-osx.liip.ch/)
3. After you've installed php, open the terminal and type in `find /usr -name php` and hit enter. You should see a few lines of paths. Make note of the one that has `/bin/php` at the end of the path. You will be needing that path for the next step.
4. Next, open a text editor, I used TextWrangler for this purpose, go to file up in on the menu bar, and select Open file by name.Then type in `~/.bash_profile`. Select Open and at the end of the .bash_profile file type in

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/php5-20120508-102213/bin/
   export PATH
   ```

   the `/usr/local/php5-20120508-102213/bin/` part of that is the path that I mentioned to make note of, minus the php at the end. If your path was different, substitute it. Just remember to leave off the php at the end.
   save and exit.
5. Last step, open the terminal and type in `php -v`. Hit enter. You should see something like:

   ```
   PHP 5.4.2 (cli) (built: May  8 2012 09:48:57) 
   Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
   Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
   with Xdebug v2.2.0rc2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
   ```

   if you're seeing that then everything is working.

> **NOTE:** Here is a good resource for working with [Command line PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-pear/) - located about 1/3 of the way down the page.

Comment: at step 4: i got
`File not found (MacOS Error code: -43)`

Comment: If `.bash_profile` doesn't exist, you can add this to `.bashrc` instead, though it will be needlessly re-executed every time you start a new shell.  Alternatively, you can create `.bash_profile`, but you will want to make sure (in most situations) to also `source .bashrc` from there then.

Comment: There should be no need to `export PATH` because the system has already done that for you.

Answer (score 11):

There is one of two things going on here, either you didn't install PHP, or PHP is installed and not currently in any of system aware paths. First I would try to find PHP and make sure it exists:

```
$ find / -name php -type f
```

You should see something like:

```
/path/to/your/php/bin/php
```

If PHP binary does exist, check your path:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

If it does not exist, recompile php.

If PHP exists on your system, make sure the path to the /bin/php file is included. You can edit your `~/.bash_profile` and add the custom path like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/php/bin/
....  
export PATH
```

Then save and reload the file to ensure your current session has access to new path changes:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

With any luck you can now do a `php -v` and see the version response.

**-- Update --**

Setting actual path:

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile

...
# Add your custom php path
PATH=$PATH:/bitnami/mampstack-osx-x86/output/php/bin/
....  
export PATH
```

Save and close, then source it:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

And now you should be able to run PHP from cli:

```
$ php -v
```

Comment: I'm thinking it's gotta be my paths. As I was telling drew010 i typed in echo $PATH in the terminal and I got this weird looking path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin. And A couple of days ago I was following along with a tutorial on how to install pear and phpunit. The tutorial had me add a new path to my .bash_profile and ever since, come to think of it, I've had problems. I already erassed the path added to the .bash_profile earlier. Do think this is the cause?

Comment: Entirely possible. That path you posted isn't out of the ordinary, did you try to locate the `php` binary using the `find` method I described in answer? Try to find it and post your findings.

Comment: yeah I forgot to mention that. The first four things that poped up were random file with permission denied at the end. Then it showed a path to php that came with bitnami MAMP stack, wordpress stack, and php for the zend framework. After that there was nothing else really php related. just a bunch of xcode and mailserver stuff.

Comment: If that doesn't work, create a temp page with `phpinfo()` and look for `Configure Command`, in there there might be a `--prefix=/path/to/nowhere`, if it is can you post it?

Comment: Yeah I tried whereis php earlier and got nothing back, so I'm pretty sure it's nowhere. The only way that I can open a temp phpinfo() is through my bitnami mamp stack and as far as the prefix goes: --prefix=/bitnami/mampstack-osx-x86/output/php. If I could somehow use that to create my yii applications, that would work. Can that be done or does it have to be PHP CLI?

Comment: Updated post, with your actual path, try it and see if it works.

Comment: unfortunately not. I'm trying to pinpoint the cause of the problem and I was able to create a new yii app about a week ago. Then I started mucking around with my .bash and a couple of other things trying to get pear and phpunit installed, and that's when I had to uninstall MAMP and switch to bitnami mamp stack, only to have the problems carry over. Maybe I'll try to recompile php. I dont' know though. I've looked into the php manual and I am still a little unclear as to how to get php recompiled and working again for CLI.

Comment: Try this from command line: `/bitnami/mampstack-osx-x86/output/php/bin/php -v` and see if it works.

Comment: Tried it. It says no such file or directory.

Comment: How did you recompile it before? Manually, or was it some part of an automated "*amp* install?

Answer (score 2):

**(On macOS Mojave 10.14.6)**

A shortcut for the mentioned 'source' command above is just the period. So you can do the following:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Add in the lines

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"
```

Hit colon W `:w` to write and colon Q to `:q` to quit VIM editor *(bonus learning)*

And now you "apply" it by entering into the terminal: `. ~/.bash_profile`

You can doublecheck the new PHP version now with `php -v` or `which php`

Answer (score 1):

In response to @MikeTheCoder, the posted export path syntax didn't work for me, but the slightly modified one following did:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5-5.6.27-20161101-100213/bin/:$PATH
```

I'm using El Capitan 10.11.6 which defaults to an earlier PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

Close your ssh tunnel and restart again for PHP is getting back and check `$ php --version`

And type the command line
sudo apt-get install php-fpm or search with newest version of php using  " sudo apt-cache search php " then you find php-fpm or php-{version}-fpm and use the following command
sudo service php-fpm restart