# How to get PHP to run from Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I was trying to install and setup Symfony2 but did something within Terminal which has messed up my PHP install. Whenever I try to run a command starting with php (ie: php --version), I get Command not found error.

I tried to follow the answer here: [How can I get PHP working again in the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557650/how-can-i-get-php-working-again-in-the-command-line)
But cannot find the .bash_profile file on my mac.

When I input `find /usr -name php` into the terminal this is what I get back:

```
/usr/include/php
/usr/lib/php
/usr/local/php5-5.5.22-20150219-213850/bin/php
/usr/local/php5-5.5.22-20150219-213850/include/php
/usr/local/php5-5.5.22-20150219-213850/lib/php
/usr/local/php5-5.6.6-20150220-225050/bin/php
/usr/local/php5-5.6.6-20150220-225050/include/php
/usr/local/php5-5.6.6-20150220-225050/lib/php
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
/usr/share/php
```

Any help would be most appreciated so that I can get this resolved and try out Symfony2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using MAMPs PHP instead after following these instructions: https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693

Within the Terminal, run `vim ~/.bash_profile`

Type i and then paste the following at the top of the file:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH
```

Hit ESC, Type `:wq`, and hit Enter

In Terminal, run `source ~/.bash_profile`

In Terminal, type in which php again and look for the updated string. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.

Comment: You are going to want to make sure you are also serving the symfony app with MAMP then. Otherwise you are going to hit stumbling blocks because of discrepancies between what extensions are available to the MAMP version you are using from the CLI, and what is available to whatever binary the webserver is using.

Comment: Actually, since restarting my mac i can no longer launch any WP sites in localhost (404) or start syfony2. Note sure whats gone wrong?

Comment: How did you install your PHP and Apache?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your `find` ouput, you are using something to manage multiple versions/compilations of `php`. The binaries you need are in the:

```
/usr/local/PHP_VERSION_IDENTIFIER/bin/php
```

In order to get it on your path you would normally symlink the binary to a typical installation location like `/usr/local/bin` like:

```
ln -s /usr/local/PHP_VERSION_IDENTIFIER/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
```

That said it looks like you are likely installed these through a package manager. You should consult its documentation to figure out how to select/activate the PHP version you want to use instead of manually making the symlink (or hardlink) yourself.